# Web application available offline from cache

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser-cache, offline-caching

I need to create a web application with offline support. When the client's computer goes offline, Javascript must redirect to another page with important information from the application.

Redirect to offline webpage

```
window.addEventListener("offline", function(e) {
   document.location.href='/offline/index.html';
}
, false);
```

How to force save page `/offline/index.html` in the browser's cache to make sure that the content will be available when the internet connection is broken?

The `/offline/index.html` page will be updated every 10 minutes (if the app is online) and the cache must be still refreshed.

--

I tried to use cache manifest in the main app's html, but this is not working correctly. The offline page was saved, but other pages in online mode are saved too. I need to cache only one file, `offline/index.html`, and I prefer to manually redirect to the offline page with a Javascript event without HTML5 offline solutions.

My cache manifest file:

```
CACHE MANIFEST

/ff/landing/js/jquery.min.js
/ff/default/js/online.js

FALLBACK:
/ /offline/index.html

NETWORK:
*
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HTML5 Manifest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_manifest_in_HTML5).

see below links

http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/offline.html

[http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/offline.html](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/)

[How should I structure my HTML5 manifest given these requirements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9422846/how-should-i-structure-my-html5-manifest-given-these-requirements)

Comment: I tried to use this solution but this not working correct. I prefer to manual redirect to offline page with Javascript event, without HTML5 offline solutions.