# cache pictures from several picture-servers with html5 manifest

Tags: html, cache-manifest

I am making my first steps with the manifest chache stuff and stumbled over some problem.

I have several picture-servers, to optimize the loading times. so an image can be delivered from i.e.:

- pics1.domain.com/images/img1
- or pics2.domain.com/images/img1
- or pics3.domain.com/images/img1

how can I arrange the caching for them?
I don't like to write down a line in the manifest file for each url, because there are very many of them.

Comment: Can't you generate the manifest file with a server-side language like PHP? This way it should be easy to vary the URLs on every request. See the answer for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885509/html5-offline-caching-with-php-driven-sites).

Comment: hmmm ... so wildcards are not posible?

Comment: Don't know exactly, but [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727774/using-wildcard-in-fallback-section-of-cache-manifest-file-html5) says that wildcards work in newer generations of browsers.

Comment: I guess I am not enough into that theme to decide which would be the best solution